# Is it possible for one oscillator to drive two ICs?

Tags: voltage, oscillator, clock, buffer

I have this [oscillator](https://www5.epsondevice.com/en/products/tcxo/tg2016smn.html) IC with  which I plan to drive a [KSZ8795](https://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/00002112B.pdf) and an [LAN9500A](https://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/aemDocuments/documents/UNG/ProductDocuments/DataSheets/LAN950x-Data-Sheet-DS00001875D.pdf) without clock buffer.

[image]

The TG2016 output load drive is 10pF for the capacitor.

The KSZ8795 can have a crystal load capacitance of 27pF maximum and the LAN9500A can have a crystal load capacitance of 8pF to 12pF.

Does the TG2016 oscillator have enough drive to drive both the devices without a clock buffer?
Will this arrangement will work? Has anyone tried such an architecture before?

Comment: Why do you plan to use that specific crystal oscillator? It would be a weird choise to use an oscillator with clipped sine wave output instead of an oscillator with standard digital output.

Comment: Thank you for the comment @Justme. I didn't know that. Can you tell me how you found that the output is a clipped sine wave output?

Comment: I clicked your link and it says this part has clipped sine wave output.

Comment: @Justme, thank you for this. Apart from this, can you help me to understand whether this will work? Whether I need to bother about the load capacitance parameters, since I am using an oscillator and not a crystal? In that case, why is the load capacitance value of 10pF given in the oscillator datasheet?

Comment: Can you then be more specific which case you mean? The original system, or by switching to a standard clock oscillator, and if yes, then which oscillator? If you don't intend to use the original oscillator then change the question.

Comment: @Justme, what confuses me is that, why is the load capacitance parameter given in the datasheet of an oscillator? Usually, only the crystal datasheet will have this parameter right? What is the significance and purpose of the load capacitance parameter for an oscillator?

Comment: So you are basically asking, why any digital circuit defines a load capacitance?

Comment: Don’t conflate crystal load capacitance with a digital output’s drive strength. The oscillator’s output driver can cope with a 10pF load. Each of the other ics input pins will present a certain capacitance and there’ll be a few more pF for the tracks and strays. At a guess, I’d say you’ll need a buffer. You add add up the numbers and you can decide.

Comment: @Justme, yes exactly. Why any digital circuit defines a load capacitance?

Comment: @Kartman, thank you for your comment. So, basically, this capacitance that you mentioned and the load capacitance of a crystal are totally different right? The capacitance aspect that you mentioned is applicable to any digital IC output, right?

Comment: @Newbie You should ask that question you want answered in the question section, not in the comment section. As to your original question, it may be impossible to answer how those chips will work if you use an oscillator with clipped sine wave output to drive them. You need to consider the output waveform and now much load each input provides, and what voltage levels they accept. Generally you would use a clock oscllator with digital logic level output.